# How do I get 1D array to accept multiple string values?

Tags: java, arrays

For my project i have to get a 1D array to accept 10 different US states and then implement several operations for the array. 
I need to use insertion sort algorithm to sort states name alphabetically A to Z without with case sensitives, and implement binary search algorithm.

My question is, to start off would I need to insert the name of every single state into a single array for it to reference off of? I'm creating the array but I'm confused as to how to start its creation. Am I starting off correctly?

```
 public class ten_states
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);

String firststate, secondstate, thirdstate, fourthstate, fifthstate, sixthstate, seventhstate, eighthstate, ninthstate,tenstate;
String states[]= new String[10];








  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
System.out.println(states[i]);
}
```

Comment: what programming language do you want to use? java?

Comment: Yeah im using java right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can put strings into an array like this:

```
String states[] = new String[10];
list[0] = "firststate";
list[1] = "secondstate";
list[2] = "thirdstate";
```

Or you could also init the string like this:

```
String[] states = {"firststate", "secondstate", "thirdstate"};
```

Here is a more advanced solution:
copy pasted from here: https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-sort-arraylist-in-java/

```
import java.util.*;
public class Details  {

    public static void main(String args[]){
       ArrayList<String> listofcountries = new ArrayList<String>();
       listofcountries.add("India");
       listofcountries.add("US");
       listofcountries.add("China");
       listofcountries.add("Denmark");

       /*Unsorted List*/
       System.out.println("Before Sorting:");
       for(String counter: listofcountries){
            System.out.println(counter);
        }

       /* Sort statement*/
       Collections.sort(listofcountries);

       /* Sorted List*/
       System.out.println("After Sorting:");
       for(String counter: listofcountries){
            System.out.println(counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I need but is collection sort another name for insertion sort?